# I18n interpolate with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have the following text in my en.yml

```
update_message: "The user updated device's name to <b>%{name}</b>"
```

and I have the following json object

```
{ "user": { "id": 1, "name: "Wagner Junior" } }
```

The service dynamically resolve the interpolation in the same way as always:

```
t('update_message', json_object)
```

but it didn't work.

I want to replace the %{name} in the update_message with the name attribute in my json object, kinda `user/name`, `user.name`, `user>name`, etc. I can't use `json_object['name']` because I will have other messages that will receive the json object.

I've tried to use different ways to do this interpolation no success.

Comment: > The service dynamically resolve the interpolation in the same way as always:

That's unclear. What the service? What does it mean "as always"? Why you cannot use `json_object['name']`? The short answer to question as it posed is: you can't do that w/o writing a specific code that will determine how to extract a key from you json object.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is expecting a flat hash for the interpolation values, not a nested one, so you can try this:

`t('update_message', name: json_object["user"]["name"])`

If you have multiple and possibly unknown depth levels, you might want to flatten your hash to receive something like `{"user_id" => 1, "user_name" => "Wagner Junior"}` you can work with.

Regarding

> I can't use json_object['name'] because I will have other messages that will receive the json object.

you didn't specify what these other JSON objects are, how they look like, and how they relate to the other messages. Here's a general idea:

```
def translate_with_json(key, json)
  if key == 'update_message'
    name = json['user']['name']
  elsif key == 'another_message'
    name = json['another']['name']
  else 
    ...
  end
  t(key, name: name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the %{name} in the update_message with the name attribute in my json object, kinda user/name, user.name, user>name, etc. I can't use json_object['name'] **because I will have other messages that will receive the json object.**

Let's say your cases dependent on context. Then you could write a function (e.g. method) that will accept the context and the object and return a corresponding value for I18n translation: *f(context, object) => value*.

```
f = ->(context, obj) { ... }
name = f.call(context1, { user: { id: 1, name: 'Wagner Junior' } })
=> 'Wagner Junior'
t('update_message', name: name)
=> "The user updated device's name to <b>Wagner Junior</b>"

name = f.call(context2, { user: [:id, 1, :name, 'Wagner Junior'] })
=> 'Wagner Junior'
t('update_message', name: name)
=> "The user updated device's name to <b>Wagner Junior</b>"
```

But only for know what the context is and how calculation a value from the context should be performed.